# How to optimize query raw when updating in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a large table(20k rows) and a query to update `parent_id` but it takes a long time, how can I optimize it? Thanks.

```
DB::table('commodity', 'c1')->whereNotNull('c1.c_level')->update([
            'c1.parent_id' => DB::raw('(SELECT c2.id
        FROM commodity c2
        WHERE c2.short_order < c1.short_order
          AND IF(c1.`c_level` > 0,
                     c2.c_level = (c1.c_level - 1),
                     c2.c_level is null)
        ORDER BY c2.short_order DESC
        LIMIT 1)')
        ]);
```

SQL:

```
update commodity as c1  set
      c1.parent_id = ( SELECT c2.id FROM commodity c2
         WHERE c2.short_order < c1.short_order
           AND IF(c1.c_level > 0,
                  c2.c_level = (c1.c_level - 1),
                  c2.c_level is null)
         ORDER BY c2.short_order DESC LIMIT 1
                     )
    where c1.c_level is not null
```

Comment: You can run it with [`EXPLAIN` statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) to see if [you can optimize indices or the like](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/)

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL so MySQL programmers who don't know Laravel can help.

Comment: this is mysql @RickJames update `commodity` as `c1` set `c1`.`parent_id` = (
        SELECT c2.id FROM commodity c2 WHERE 
            c2.short_order < c1.short_order AND IF(c1.`c_level` > 0, c2.c_level = (c1.c_level - 1), c2.c_level is null) 
        ORDER BY c2.short_order DESC LIMIT 1) 
    where `c1`.`c_level` is not null

Comment: It would be better to have a multi-table Update -- that is with a `JOIN`, not a correlated subquery.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It may be advisable to have `INDEX(short_order)`.

Answer (score 0):

you must use index in this case, first create new migration:

```
php artisan make:migration add_index_to_commodity --table=commodity
```

then in file that generated do this:

```
Schema::table('commodity', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->index('short_order');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the `parent_id`. Then try to update with different query.

Comment: Could you please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68496484/edit) the actual code to your answer in order to make it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

```
update `commodity` as `c1` set `c1`.`parent_id` = (
        SELECT c2.id FROM commodity c2 WHERE 
            c2.short_order < c1.short_order AND IF(c1.`c_level` > 0, c2.c_level = (c1.c_level - 1), c2.c_level is null) 
        ORDER BY c2.short_order DESC LIMIT 1) 
    where `c1`.`c_level` is not null
```